# ionic 3 with geofire angularfire2

Tags: angularfire2, ionic3, geofire

How the right way to use geofire in ionic 3,
Im using ionic 3.5  firebase: "4.1.3",
    "geofire": "4.1.2","angularfire2": "4.0.0-rc.1",

```
constructor( public angularfireDatabase: AngularFireDatabase,
private geolocation: Geolocation) { } 



ionViewDidLoad() {
  this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) =>
   this.geoQuery= this.geoFire.query({
    center: [resp.coords.latitude, resp.coords.longitude],
    radius: 20  //kilometers
   });            
   this.geoQuery.on("key_entered", function (key, location, distance) {
      console.log('from geofire ' +location, ' key ' + key,distance);
      this.angularfireDatabase.object('/products/'+key).subscribe((product) => {
          this.products.push(product);
      });
   });
  }).catch((error) => {
   console.log('Error getting location', error);
 });
}
```

return this error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'angularfireDatabase' of undefined
at products.ts:76
at geofire.js:685
```

content of geofire.d.ts

```
interface GeoQuery {
    center(): number[];
    radius(): number;
    updateCriteria(criteria: GeoQueryUpdateCriteria);
    on(eventType: EventType, callback: (key:string, location: number[], distance: number) => void): GeoCallbackRegistration;
    cancel();
} 
class GeoFire {
    constructor(ref: any);
    ref(): any;
    set(key: string, loc: number[]): Promise<void>;
    get(key: string): Promise<number[]>;
    remove(key: string): Promise<void>;
    query(criteria: GeoQueryCriteria): GeoQuery;
    static distance(location1: number[], location2: number[]);  
}
```

How is the right way to declare typescript?.Simple example also not working

```
    public pubVar:any;
    constructor( public angularfireDatabase: AngularFireDatabase,
    private geolocation: Geolocation) { } 



   ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.pubVar = 'hii';
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) =>
      this.geoQuery= this.geoFire.query({
       center: [resp.coords.latitude, resp.coords.longitude],
       radius: 20  //kilometers
      });            
     this.geoQuery.on("key_entered", function (key, location, distance) {
      console.log('from geofire ' +location, ' key ' + key,distance);
      console.log(this.pubVar);


   }).catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error getting location', error);
   });
 }
```

also return

```
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pubVar' of undefined
```

Comment: using  https://github.com/daveozoalor/geofire-firebase-not-working-in-ionic-fix

Answer (score 0):

The keyword "this" is not defined or bound inside of your callback so it comes back as undefined. If you use the fat arrow notation, with the key_entered event, "this" will be within scope in the callback:

```
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) =>
   this.geoQuery= this.geoFire.query({
    center: [resp.coords.latitude, resp.coords.longitude],
    radius: 20  //kilometers
   });            
   this.geoQuery.on("key_entered", (key, location, distance) => {
      console.log('from geofire ' +location, ' key ' + key,distance);
      this.angularfireDatabase.object('/products/'+key).subscribe((product) => {
          this.products.push(product);
      });
   });
  }).catch((error) => {
   console.log('Error getting location', error);
 });
```